# Python API call - loop / nextpagetoken

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I'm brand new to python and api as well.

I'm trying to use a endpoint we have at work.

We have an API we are using a lot, we also have an UI. But using the UI we can only extract 10.000 records at the time.
There is no limit on the api.

I have found a small piece of code - but i need to add a nextpagetoken.

My code looks like this:

```
login_url = 'https://api.ubsend.io/v1/auth/login'
username = 'xxxxx'
password = 'xxxxx'
omitClaims = "true"
session = requests.Session()
session.headers['Accept'] = "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
response = session.post(
login_url,
json={'username': username, 'password': password},
headers={'VERSION': '3'},
)
response.raise_for_status()
response_data = response.json()
print(response_data)
```

This gives me the **AccessToken**.

Then I call:

```
getevents = 'https://api.ubsend.io/v1/reporting/shipments?'
data ={'client_id': 13490, 'created_after': '2020-05-01T00:00', 'created_before': '2021-05-02T00:00'} req.prepare_url(getevents, data)
events = requests.get(req.url, headers={'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + response_data['accessToken'], Content-Type': 'application/json'})
events.json()
```

Which returns:

```
 'nextPageToken': 'NjA4ZDc3YzNkMjBjODgyYjBhMWVkMTVkLDE2MTk4ODM5NzA3MDE='}
```

So I want to loop my script - **until nextPageToken is blank** ....

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Edit thanks for the update.  I think this might be the solution we're looking for.  You might have to do some poking around to figure out exactly what the name of the `page_token` URL parameter should be.

```py
has_next = True
getevents = 'https://api.ubsend.io/v1/reporting/shipments?'
token = None
while has_next:
    data ={'client_id': 13490, 'created_after': '2020-05-01T00:00', 'created_before': '2021-05-02T00:00'}
    if token:
        # I don't know the proper name for this URL parameter.
        data['page_token'] = token
    req.prepare_url(getevents, data)
    events = requests.get(req.url, headers={'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + response_data['accessToken'], Content-Type: 'application/json'})
    token = events.json().get('nextPageToken')
    if not token:
        has_next = False
```

I made a slight typo.  It should be `events.json().get('nextPageToken')` I believe.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Hi 

i just assigned the getevents to the same url.
My api doc says that nextpagetoken is a query parameter, so I was thinking maybe it should be included in data variable?
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-845e135cb759> in <module>
     11 
     12 
---> 13     if events.get('nextPageToken'):
     14         getevents = 'https://api.ubsend.io/v1/reporting/shipments?'
     15     else:

AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Made a couple edits.  I think putting it in the data object should work.  You could also try putting ```params={'page_token':token}``` directly into the get request.  You might have to try a few names as well until you find what works.  There's a nice app called Postman that lets you make API requests very easily if you need a tool to test a bunch of them with.  ```events.json().get('nextPageToken')``` should work at the very least.